# require_once show warning and fatal error but in correct dir

Tags: php, require

My web is running normally until i create index.php and show me this error messege.

> Warning: require_once(../_asset/faker/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\covid_config\config.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../_asset/faker/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\belajar\covid_config\config.php on line 10

This my program that maybe cause the error (index.php)

```
include "_config/config.php";
```

And this my config.php

```
require_once "../_asset/faker/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/autoload.php";
```

My folder tables: start from htdocs

```
belajar-covid-_asset
             |-_config
             |-auth
             |-dashboard
             |-index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

On `require`, `require_once`, `include` and `include_once` statements, PHP search the source file basing on the following priority order:

1. The full pathname, if any (e.g. `include 'c:/my_include/autoload.php';`)
2. The `include_path` (in your case is `C:\xampp\php\PEAR`)
3. The calling script's own directory
4. The current working directory

The file you require ('../_asset/faker/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/autoload.php') is not in any of these locations.

[See PHP manual for details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)